# Is there any difference at all between suffix(from:) and dropFirst(_:)?

Tags: swift, swift3, subsequence

It just occurred to me that when working with subsequences in Swift,

`func suffix(from: Int)` seems to be identical to just `dropFirst(_:)` (Obviously, you just change the input value from say "3" to "7" in the case of an array of length "10".)

Just to repeat that. So: of course, for an array of say **length ten.  What I mean is `func suffix(from: Int)` with "2" would be the same as `dropFirst(_:)` with "8"**, for example.

Similarly `upTo` / `through` seem to be identical to `dropLast(_:)`

Other than convenience **is there any difference at all**?

(Perhaps in error conditions, performance, or?)

I was wondering whether, in fact, inside Swift one or the other is just implemented by calling the other?

Comment: It would appear that they both end up calling subscript method: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/3f534c254df2b90d176b7daea3cd7a6a9cfbfa5e/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift

Comment: @JoeBlow It does – [the subscript method of `Collection` that takes a `Range<Self.Index>` input](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection/1641249-subscript) returns a `SubSequence`.

Comment: @JoeBlow Nope, [`suffix(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection/1641744-suffix) also returns a `SubSequence`

Comment: `ArraySlice<Element>` is `Array<Element>`'s `SubSequence` @JoeBlow :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are completely different.

- [`suffix(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection/1641372-suffix)

  - Defined by the [`Collection`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection) protocol.
  - Returns a [`Subsequence`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection/subsequence) from a given *starting [`Index`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/indexablebase/index)*.
  - Documented time complexity of O(1) (you can [see its default implementation here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift#L1486)).
  - Runtime error if the index you pass is out of range.
- [`dropFirst(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/1641666-dropfirst)

  - Defined by the [`Sequence`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence) protocol.
  - Returns a [`SubSequence`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/subsequence) with a given maximum *number of elements* removed from the head of the sequence.
  - Has a documented time complexity of O(n)*. Although [its default implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift#L1157) actually has a time complexity of O(1), this just postpones the O(n) walk through the dropped elements until iteration.
  - Returns an empty subsequence if the number you input is greater than the sequence's length.

*As with all protocol requirement documented time complexities, it's possible for the conforming type to have an implementation with a lower time complexity. For example, a [`RandomAccessCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/randomaccesscollection/)'s `dropFirst(_:)` method will run in O(1) time.

---

However, when it comes to `Array`, these methods just *happen* to behave identically (except for the handling of out of range inputs).

This is because  `Array` has an `Index` of type `Int` that starts from `0` and sequentially counts up to `array.count - 1`, therefore meaning that a subsequence with the first `n` elements dropped is *the same subsequence* that starts from the index `n`.

Also because `Array` is a `RandomAccessCollection`, both methods will run in O(1) time.

Comment: Hamish, I think you truly answered the question right here: **"However, when it comes to Array, these methods *just happen* to behave identically (except for the handling of out of range inputs)."**  Totally amesome - thanks.  Hamish is even my nephew's name  :)

Comment: Happy to help @JoeBlow :)

Answer (score 2):

You're right that they're connected, but yes there is a difference. From the docs:

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(numbers.suffix(2))
// Prints "[4, 5]"
print(numbers.suffix(10))
// Prints "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]"
```

versus

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(numbers.dropFirst(2))
// Prints "[3, 4, 5]"
print(numbers.dropFirst(10))
// Prints "[]"
```

In the first example, suffix(2) returns *only the last* two elements, whereas dropFirst(2) returns *all but the first* two elements. Similarly, they behave differently wrt. arguments longer than the sequence is long. (Additionally, suffix will only work on finite sequences.)

Likewise with prefix and dropLast. Another way of thinking about it, for a sequence of length n, prefix(k) == dropLast(n-k), where k <= n.

Comment: Hang on Colin!  (Note my new example in bold in the question.)  In your example, to go from suffix to dropFirst, you'd use "2" then change to "3".  "10" you would change to "0".  (Well, "-5", but we'd understand to make it "0" in such conversions.)  They would **seem to be identical.**

Comment: To be clear!  You see your final sentence: "Another........." that is in fact precisely what I'm asking: are they ACTUALLY the same thing, prefix(k) === dropLast(n-k) ??

Comment: I'm not sure how functions that produce different output with the same arguments are identical?

Comment: Hey @ColinBarrett ! - right, of course I meant trivially mapping the relevant argument.  In any event, Rob above seems to have answered the question - yes, they're identical, they call the same substrate.

Comment: @ColinBarrett Note that your answer is talking about `suffix(_:)`, not `suffix(from:)` – which is what OP is asking about.

Answer (score 2):

Biggest difference IMO is that `dropFirst()` doesn't expose your code to out-of-range index errors. So you can safely use either form of `dropFirst` on an empty array, while the `prefix` / `suffix` methods can crash on an empty array or with out-of-range parameters.

So `dropFirst()` FTW if you'd prefer an empty array result when you specify more elements than are available rather than a crash, or if you don't want / need to check to make sure your the index you'll be using is less than the `array.count`, etc.

Conceptually, I think this makes sense for the operation as named, considering that `first` is an optional-typed property that returns the first element *if it exists*.  Saying `dropFirst(3)` means "remove the maybe-present first element if it exists, and do so three times"

Comment: Hold it - that would be awesome, but unfortunately `dropFirst()` immediately (and entirely stupidly) crashes on negative numbers.

Comment: But yeah, you're 100% right that Apple graciously made it "pointlessly crash less".

Comment: @JoeBlow  It _is_ surprising that it doesn't require a UInt.  I supposed I should clarify that it won't crash with any "logically feasible" / non-negative parameters.

Comment: You know, it would take some thought to figure out if - in fact - they both crash "in the same way". You know what I mean ?!  heh.  Rob has critically pointed out that they (apparently) use the same underlying code, so :/   I can't read computer code or documentation, so I can't work it out.  (It's **astoundingly absurd** that for such a simple operation, you have to rewrite your own calls  :/  )

Comment: @JoeBlow I don't think it's pointlessly crashing less.  When doing functional-style chaining on an array, e.g. `array.filter{ $0 > 10 }.dropFirst(3).reduce{ + }` you don't have to insert additional lines of imperative range-checking in the middle.  I think for many chained operation cases, `dropFirst()` is a distinctively better option.

Comment: @DanielHall It's not actually not really surprising that it doesn't take a `UInt` – the Swift team recommend using `Int`s even when the values are known to be non-negative, as it aids interoperability.

Comment: @Hamish  I can see that, but I think that interoperability will eventually be a relic, and even now interoperability trumping type checking and safety in this case is...questionable

Comment: I think the whole thing is unbelievably stupid.  There is never, ever, ever, ever, ever, ever, ever, ever, ever any situation where you would want anything other than the obvious result.  (ie, return a nil set and/or range, at worst).  if I ask you as a human "what's the billionth item in this set of ten" the answer is **the empty set**. Anyway just a rant.

Comment: @JoeBlow  Personally I find `dropFirst()` to behave exactly as expected. If I have an array of 2 elements and drop the first three elements encountered, I get an empty array.  If I started with an empty array and drop the first 10 elements in it, I get an empty array.  Or if I have a 10 element array and drop the first 6, I get a 4 element array. Makes sense to me and is useful when I don't want to specify the "obviously, only drop elements until you run out of elements" part imperatively. Whereas prefix/suffix/range-based functions imply strict valid start and end requirements.

Comment: @DanielHall Yeah, I do agree that the design choice is questionable – trading convenience for safety does seem to somewhat contradict the ideals of Swift.

Comment: Hey DH and H, I clicked a bounty to say thanks, stupidly on SO you can't click out two bounties.  I think the insights you two guys worked out here are quite incredible.  Amazing stuff!  Cheers

Comment: Thanks @JoeBlow!  Appreciate the bounty and the discussion you kicked off!